# HibernateException: getCriteriaBuilder no es valido sin transaccion activa

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, transacciones

estoy desarrollando una aplicación Java Web con Spring MVC y Hibernate, soy nuevo en el desarrollo con dichos frameworks y estoy intentanto listar unos registros pero me sale lo siguiente:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: getCriteriaBuilder is not valid without active transaction
```

Excepcion completa:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: getCriteriaBuilder is not valid without active transaction
at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:351)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.getCriteriaBuilder(Unknown Source)
at com.edwin.spring.dao.PersonDAOImpl.listPersons(PersonDAOImpl.java:34)
at com.edwin.spring.service.PersonServiceImpl.listPersons(PersonServiceImpl.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.listPersons(Unknown Source)
at com.edwin.spring.controllers.PersonController.list(PersonController.java:35)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:625)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1372)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

La excepción es lanzada en la clase PersonDAOImpl en esta linea

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
```

PersonDAOImpl.java

```
@Repository("personDao")
public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void save(Person person) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(person);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Person person) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(person);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Person> listPersons() {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Person> criteria = builder.createQuery(Person.class);
        Root<Person> employeeRoot=criteria.from(Person.class);
        criteria.select(employeeRoot);
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
    }
}
```

Al parecer no funciona porque el llamado no se encuentra en una transacción pero utilizo la anotación `@Transactional` de Spring en el Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

    @Autowired
    private PersonDAO personDao;

     @Override
     public void save(Person person) {
         personDao.save(person);
     }

     @Override
     public void delete(Person person) {
         personDao.delete(person);
     }

     @Override
     public List<Person> listPersons() {
         return personDao.listPersons();
     }

     @Override
     public Person getById(Integer id) {
         return personDao.getById(id);
     }

}
```

Este es el controlador

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/persons")
public class PersonController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonController.class);

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/all", "/list"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list(Model model) {
        logger.info("Se ingresa al método de listar personas");
        List<Person> persons = personService.listPersons();
        logger.info("listando personas, hay un total de " + persons.size());
        model.addAttribute("persons", persons.size());
        return "persons";
    }
}
```

Este es el web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
    and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

El archivo servlet-contex.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.edwin.spring" />

<!-- Datasource -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:hibernate.properties" />

<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    id="dataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</beans:bean>

<!--SessionFactory -->
<beans:bean id="hibernateSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" value="#{dataSource}" />
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.edwin.spring.model" />
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
            </beans:prop>
            <!--<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop> -->
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory"/>
</beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Y por ultimo el archivo de hibernate.properties que está en src/main/resources

```
#DB properties:
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring
jdbc.user=root
jdbc.password=1234

#Hibernate Configuration:
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
```

He intentado colocar el `@Transactional` en el método directamente y tampoco me ha funcionado, no sé que estará sucediendo o si algo está mal configurado, de antemano les agradezco :).

Comment: Solo falla ese metodo? los demas funcionan bien?

Comment: @jasilva los demas métodos tambien fallan como el saveOrUpdate, lanzan la misma excepción y causa

Comment: Si cambias `@Autowired private SessionFactory sessionFactory;` por `@Resource private SessionFactory sessionFactory;`

Comment: @jasilva sale el mismo error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya vi por donde va el problema, en tu configuración aparte de lo "común" tienes esto

```
<beans:prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</beans:prop>
<beans:prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">true</beans:prop>
<beans:prop key="hibernate.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</beans:prop>
<beans:prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</beans:prop>
<beans:prop key="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</beans:prop>
```

Algunas se usan en configuraciones JTA, pero si tenemos configurado nuestro factory como local, no lo necesitamos.

Probando con la configuración si removemos `hibernate.current_session_context_class` ya no deberias tener problemas

Comment: Perfecto! Ha funcionado quitando la línea que has mencionado, gracias!! :)

Comment: @edwin22 Te sugiero que tambien quites `hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion` ya que no sirve de nada si tu config es local. Si te ayudo esta respuesta marcala como respuesta aceptada pulsado el boton en forma de V en la izquierda, asi ayudaras a futuros usuarios con el mismo problema y ganaras reputación en el sitio.

Comment: ok, como soy nuevo usando spring y hibernate la configuración la tuve que hacer basandome en varios ejemplos por blogs y pues no se dejaba claro lo que hace cada propiedad.